# Is there a group with these properties?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Is there a group $G$ with identity element $e$ such that $st \ne ts$ and $st^{-1} \ne ts$ for all $s \in S$ and all $t \in T$, where $S = \{s \in G | s = s^{-1}, s \ne e\}$ and $T = \{t \in G | t \ne t^{-1}\}$?
I have found that in the symmetric group $S_3$,  $st \ne ts$ for all $s \in S$ and all $t \in T$. But in $S_3$, $st^{-1} = ts$ for all $s \in S$ and all $t \in T$.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: If $G$ were the trivial group (identity element only), then $S$ would be empty and your property would be vacuously true.

Comment: @hardmath Or just take $G$ to be torsion-free.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Are you suggesting that $G$ is such a group? Because the other condition on $G$ is that involutions in $G$ do not centralize non-involutions. An example of such a group is $A_4$.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven: I seem to have missed the non-centralizing condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that you intend $G$ to be finite, and $S$ and $T$ to both be non-empty. There are infinitely many such groups. One source of examples is to take a direct product of copies of $C_2\times C_2$, and then have a single element of order $3$ act on these as in the group $A_4$. As a group of permutations, this involves taking the Klein four group, $\{1,(1,2)(3,4),(1,3)(2,4),(1,4)(2,3)\}$, shifting it by $4n$, so $\{1,(5,6)(7,8),(5,7)(6,8),(5,8)(6,7)\}$ and so on, and then including an element of order $3$ acting as $(1,2,3)(5,6,7)(9,10,11)...$. There are many more such examples, for example one of order $2^n(2^n-1)$ for all $n\geq 2$. ($A_4$ is the smallest such group.)

From a more advanced viewpoint, using the thesis of Fowler from 1952, one obtains that the Sylow $2$-subgroup is normal. Then the acting group, which is faithful, must have the property that every element, of odd order, has no fixed points on the $\mathbb{F}_2$-vector space.

Comment: If you ever again your find yourself asking, "I suppose you intend..." or "I am guessing you mean...", In and ***answer*** that's a signal that you should be commenting instead and asking for clarification, and only after the asker improves the post so no guessing on your part is needed, you can answer it.  Please also review: [Enforcement of Quality Standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards).  As the question has been closed, that's another signal that you likely answered too soon.

Comment: @amWhy I was originally going to do that, and I knew the question was going to be closed, but I thought about it and the answer was interesting and non-trivial, even though the question was bad. Consequently, I provided an answer rather than voting to close, although perhaps I should have done both.

Comment: Note that a poorly written question, when closed, and/or deleted, and you think it could be made a better question, and have an answer you think is valuable, You can ask, in a separate post, the question that could have been asked, (a good question), and also answer it.  But thanks for the response.